# user have to check n'th item first than n-1 will be enable for check

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have create checkbox with select all. It works very fine.now I want I will able to check "select all" but can not select item 1 or item 2 or item 3. I should select item 5 first than only item 4 will be enable to select 3, 2, 1 will remain disable, after select item 5 and item 4 than item 3 will be enable to select and item 2 and 1 remain disable to select.It will continue until 1.
How can i do that please some one help me.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#select_all').on('click',function(){
        if(this.checked){
            $('.cbox').each(function(){
                 this.checked = true;
             });
         }else{
              $('.cbox').each(function(){
                this.checked = false;
             });
        }
    });
    
    $('.cbox').on('click',function(){
        if($('.cbox:checked').length == $('.cbox').length){
            $('#select_all').prop('checked',true);
        }else{
            $('#select_all').prop('checked',false);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="main">
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="select_all" onclick="cl(this)"  /> Select all</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" class="cbox" value="1"/>Item 1</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" class="cbox" value="2"/>Item 2</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" class="cbox" value="3"/>Item 3</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" class="cbox" value="4"/>Item 4</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" class="cbox" value="5"/>Item 5</li>
      Total Amount : <input id="Totalcost" > </input>
```

here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/Nasra/f4xrhq40/1/

Comment: **P.S.:** a  `ul`-tag couldn't contain an `input` element. Replace this tag or nest it into a `li`-tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [.index( selector )](https://api.jquery.com/index/) in order to get the index of current selected checkbox.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.cbox:not(:last)').prop('disabled', true);

  $('#select_all').on('change', function (e) {
    var isChecked = this.checked;
    $('.cbox').get().reverse().forEach(function(ele, index) {
      ele.checked = isChecked;
      $(ele).trigger('change');
    });
  });

  $('.cbox').on('change', function (e) {
    if (this.checked) {
      var sIndex = (+$(this).index('.cbox') - 2);
      var selCriteria = (sIndex < 0) ? '.cbox' : '.cbox:gt(' + sIndex + ')';
      $(selCriteria).prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
      var sIndex = +$(this).index('.cbox');
      var selCriteria = '.cbox:lt(' + sIndex + ')';
      $(selCriteria).prop({'disabled': true, 'checked': false});
      $('.cbox:last').prop('disabled', false);
    }
    if ($('.cbox:checked').length == $('.cbox').length){
      $('#select_all').prop('checked',true);
    } else{
      $('#select_all').prop('checked',false);
    }
    var tot = 0;
    $('.cbox:checked').get().forEach(function(ele, index) {
      tot += parseFloat(ele.value);
    });
    $('#Totalcost').val(tot);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<ul class="main">
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="select_all" /> Select all</li>
    <ul>
        <li><input name="inv_ammount" type="checkbox" class="cbox" value="1"/>Item 1</li>
        <li><input name="inv_ammount" type="checkbox" class="cbox" value="2"/>Item 2</li>
        <li><input name="inv_ammount" type="checkbox" class="cbox" value="3"/>Item 3</li>
        <li><input name="inv_ammount" type="checkbox" class="cbox" value="4"/>Item 4</li>
        <li><input name="inv_ammount" type="checkbox" class="cbox" value="5"/>Item 5</li>
        Total Amount : <input id="Totalcost" />
    </ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: It works! :) Thanks a lot, thank you so much #gaetanoM

Comment: I've got an issue! when I pass value.

Comment: I've got an issue! when I pass value. 1. if check "select all" then unchek "item 5" than "total amount" carry value but it should be empty. 2. if i check "item 5" than "item 4" and then uncheck "item 5" than total amount field carry value of "item 4" but "total amount" field should empty. could you please lookup my code again.  here is the link: http://codepen.io/nasra/pen/mEgQGr?editors=1010

Comment: Exactly Same what I wanted...I really really appreciate your help.Thank you so much.